SQL Developer Output doens't display data of tables with XML columns
This is a question that querying me for a while. I use SQL Developer on a duplicated testing database, then update the query to a backend application that connects to the real-time database. Notice that tables with XML columns only work in the backend application but output empty results in SQL developer.
I saw this thread
SQL Developer doesn't display XML
My version is 23
I have tried Tools - Preferences - Database -Advanced - Display XML Value In Grid and table alias, but they don't work.
Even though I query a non-XML column in those tables, I still get an empty result.


I can use the backend application to test those XML tables and that's fine, but now there is a challenge to import those tables into Power BI,where also shows the empty results.
I was wondering if I could do something in SQL script to make those tables visible.
update:
SQL Developer Version 23.1.0.097
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
DDL
CREATE TABLE "DSI"."SVC_RQST" 
   (    "RQS_ID" NUMBER DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SBS_GUI" RAW(16) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COM_TOK_GUI" RAW(16) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FUN_PRM" "SYS"."XMLTYPE"  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CON_PRM" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" , 
    "DAT_CRE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SER_GUI" RAW(16) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "SVC_RQST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("RQS_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BUTPROD_INDX"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BUTPROD_DATA"   NO INMEMORY 
 XMLTYPE COLUMN "FUN_PRM" STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML (
  TABLESPACE "BUTPROD_DATA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  NOCACHE LOGGING  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ALLOW NONSCHEMA DISALLOW ANYSCHEMA 
 XMLTYPE COLUMN "CON_PRM" STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML (
  TABLESPACE "BUTPROD_DATA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192
  NOCACHE LOGGING  NOCOMPRESS  KEEP_DUPLICATES 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ALLOW NONSCHEMA DISALLOW ANYSCHEMA 

Sample Row
    RQS_ID 2275473,
    SBS_GUI 9D2749A0328E42DAB0D770495CD4D2AA,
    COM_TOK_GUI 1F9A7BAC0EB08236E06301644B0A4EBB,
    FUN_PRM <OrdersGet>
      <Service Name="OrdersGet"/>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Code="RestrictionCode" Value="5"/>
        <Parameter Code="XMLScope" Value="2"/>
        <Parameter Code="PurchasePrice" Value="N"/>
        <Parameter Code="SellingPrice" Value="N"/>
        <Parameter Code="CheckPointResponsible" Value="N"/>
        <Parameter Code="FirstTopElements" Value="30"/>
        <Parameter Code="ClearQueue" Value="Y"/>
      </Parameters>
      <Companies>
        <Company>
          <TranscodificationCode>ORDERS_GET</TranscodificationCode>
          <Code>ABT</Code>
          <ProfileCode>P18</ProfileCode>
          <MenuCode>DSI_TMS_ORD_GET</MenuCode>
          <EntityCode>ORDER</EntityCode>
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Code="ThirdPartyCode" Value="P18"/>
          </Parameters>
          <Agencies>
            <Agency>
              <Code>01</Code>
            </Agency>
          </Agencies>
        </Company>
      </Companies>
    </OrdersGet>    
    DAT_CRE 14/08/2024  07:03:01,
    SER_GUI 1F9CEFF33749BB94E06301644B0ADD47


It's not a display problem, it's just not FINDING any records.  Are you sure that second system contains all the same records as the first system?

please update your question with the DDL for your table - there's more than 1 way to store XML in an oracle database, AND a sample row/document we can use to reproduce your environment. Also include version of Oracle Database you are using

They sync data to the second system periodically. These tables couldn't be all empty. I will find out DDL and update a sample row.
